# pandas: sort grouped dataframe by frequency of group members

Tags: pandas

I am interested in sorting a grouped dataframe by the number of entries for each group. As far as I can see, I can either sort by the group labels or not at all. Say I have 10 entries that belong to three groups. Group A has 6 members, group B has three members, and group C has 1 member. Now when I e.g. do a grouped.describe(), I would like the output to be ordered so that the group with the most entries is shown first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would unstack the statistics from `describe()`, then you can simply use `sort()`, so:

```
incsv = StringIO("""Group,Value
B,1
B,2
B,3
C,8
A,5
A,10
A,15
A,25
A,35
A,40""")

df = pd.read_csv(incsv)

groups = df.groupby('Group').describe().unstack()

       Value                                                  
       count       mean        std  min    25%  50%   75%  max
Group                                                         
A          6  21.666667  14.023789    5  11.25   20  32.5   40
B          3   2.000000   1.000000    1   1.50    2   2.5    3
C          1   8.000000        NaN    8   8.00    8   8.0    8


dfstats.xs('Value', axis=1).sort('count', ascending=True)

       count       mean        std  min    25%  50%   75%  max
Group                                                         
C          1   8.000000        NaN    8   8.00    8   8.0    8
B          3   2.000000   1.000000    1   1.50    2   2.5    3
A          6  21.666667  14.023789    5  11.25   20  32.5   40
```

I reversed the sort just for illustration because it was already sorted by default, but you can sort anyway you want of course.

Bonus for anyone who can sort by count without dropping or stacking the 'Value' level. :)

Comment: try this as your last step: ``groups.sort([('Value','count')],ascending=False)``, though not sure its actually more useful

Comment: Definitely better than my .xs( attempt, I didn't realize sort could use tuples, which is nice.

Comment: Thank you! In addition to solving my problem at hand, you also taught me something useful about pandas in general.